# Swift: arrays of CountableRange<Int>: Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

Tags: swift

I have the following function:

`private func randomName<T: Object & TextName>(from results: Results<T>, crossNameChance: Int, textRanges: [[CountableRange<Int>]]?) -> String`

it works fine if I pass `nil` for `textRanges`, however it generates an error saying:

> Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

when I pass:

`[[0...1], [2...3], [1...1, 3...3], [0...0, 2...2]]`

as argument for `textRanges`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax `a...b` returns a `CountableClosedRange`, which is a different type from `CountableRange`. Either change the parameter to be `textRanges: [[CountableClosedRange<Int>]]?`, or change each interval to be of the form `a..<b`.

You can figure this out by breaking out the value you tried to pass as a parameter:

```
let textRanges: [[CountableRange<Int>]]? = [[0...1], [2...3], [1...1, 3...3], [0...0, 2...2]]
```

will give you the more helpful error message:

```
error: cannot convert value of type 'CountableClosedRange<Int>' to expected element type 'CountableRange<Int>'
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize the difference.

Comment: Note that you should declare textRanges as  `[CountableClosedRange<Int>]` and `let textRanges: [CountableClosedRange<Int>] = [0...1, 2...3, 1...1, 3...3, 0...0, 2...2]` or simply let Xcode infer the type `let textRanges = [0...1, 2...3, 1...1, 3...3, 0...0, 2...2]`

Comment: You can check the inferred type by option-clicking the resulting object `textRanges `

Comment: @LeoDabus it seems from the original example that the user does want the double-nested array, ie `[[CountableClosedRange<Int>]]`, for the sake of grouping

Comment: @Connor yes I just noticed there are some ranges grouped